# React activeClassName property of NavLink not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I've been trying to use the *activeClassName* property of *NavLink* for applying a certain color and background to the links/anchors. But the changes weren't displayed upon clicking. I'm attaching the js and CSS snippets below

```js
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import './navbar.css';

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <div className='navbar'>
      <div className='navbar__left'>
        <NavLink to='/'>Clubhub</NavLink>
      </div>

      <div className='navbar__right'>
        <NavLink activeClassName='active_link' to='/'>
          Home
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink activeClassName='active_link' to='/membership'>
          Membership
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink activeClassName='active_link' to='/booking'>
          Booking
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink activeClassName='active_link' to='/profile'>
          Profile
        </NavLink>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

```css
.active_link {
  background-color: #224461;
  color: white;
}
```

Please help me figure out the issue.
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [react-router docs](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink/classname-string-func),

> In React Router v6, **activeClassName** will be removed and you should use
> the function **className** to apply classnames to either active or
> inactive NavLink components.

Here is an updated version :-

```
import React from "react";
import { NavLink, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import "./navbar.css";

const classNameFunc = ({ isActive }) => (isActive ? "active_link" : "");

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="navbar">
        <div className="navbar__left">
          <NavLink to="/">Clubhub</NavLink>
        </div>

        <div className="navbar__right">
          <NavLink className={classNameFunc} to="/">
            Home
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink className={classNameFunc} to="/membership">
            Membership
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink className={classNameFunc} to="/booking">
            Booking
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink className={classNameFunc} to="/profile">
            Profile
          </NavLink>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

The above code in action :-

[image: Edit React-rourt-dom-NavLink]

Comment: Thanks, man! It finally worked. I spent way too much time on this.